# 504 error on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we have a CakePHP application on Elastic Beanstalk and it appear to work fine, but we have an api that keeps returning 504 error, for which we have tried to edit the max_execution_timeout to 300 inside the configuration files and also manually through the ssh, with rebooting apache afterwards, but the script stops every time at 60 seconds of execution.

Please if you have any idea what could we change it would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: The script we call is very long including several soap calls

Comment: Figured out it was a load balancer idle timeout problem - increased that value and the script executed :)