# 60 Second Timeout on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a single-instance (NO load balancer) Docker container (NO proxy server) that times out at exactly sixty seconds no matter what I do.

Yes, I'm aware of the many seemingly "duplicate" questions. I've been trying to solve this problem for 40+ hours. I've seen them all.

Every single answer to these questions informs the user that they must change the settings of NGINX or the load balancer.

However, I have NEITHER NGINX or a load balancer for the environment, yet it still times out. I am mostly convinced that this is an AWS bug.

I have an endpoint titled `time_test` for the mini server I created. When I make a POST request to the endpoint, I get a timeout at exactly 60 seconds (the request throws an exception on my end).

Here's the Python code to make the request.

```
import requests
url = f"http://...us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
time_to_sleep = 65
url += f"time_test?time_to_sleep={time_to_sleep}"
response = requests.post(url=url, timeout=10000)
```

This throws an `HTTPSException` error, indicating that the server terminated the response, always at exactly 60 seconds.

However, the logs show a successful response.

My logs (specifically, "eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/eb-blahblah-stdouterr.log) shows

`[01/Jun/2022 22:05:49] "POST /time_test?time_to_sleep=65 HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Note the `200` successful status code.

I'm going to continue to find an answer to this problem, which seemingly has none, and will report back if so. Any help with how to change the environment to accept >60 second requests would be greatly appreciated. Please don't reply, "You should have shorter request times." Not helpful or applicable.

(Platform = Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.10)

Related:

- [How to increase FastAPI timeout in Docker to be deployed on AWS EB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482084/how-to-increase-fastapi-timeout-in-docker-to-be-deployed-on-aws-eb)
- [Elastic Beanstalk WebSocket Connection Dropped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59774710/elastic-beanstalk-websocket-connection-dropped)
- [PHP beanstalk application giving 504 errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72032037/php-beanstalk-application-giving-504-errors)
- [Blazor Server Side - Frequent 504 errors in AWS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528363/blazor-server-side-frequent-504-errors-in-aws-environment)
- [504 error on aws elastic beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389985/504-error-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)
- [Deploying ebextensions on Elastic beanstalk and EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681162/deploying-ebextensions-on-elastic-beanstalk-and-ec2)

Comment: If you're not using NGINX, I assume you are using Apache? Or what are you using as the webserver?

Comment: You can choose "no proxy" in the configuration when the platform is Docker

Comment: FWIW, I tried "No Proxy," NGINX, and Apache. Same issue with all 3.

Answer (score 0):

AWS bug. It magically started working after I reported this issue to support. No changes. Considering it magically stopped working, that's the conclusion I've come to.

Comment: And it magically just stopped working. Again, no changes. Beyond frustrating.

Comment: So this second time, I got a different error than the first: 

``requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))``

Guess what the cause was? My VPN! Turned it off, and everything worked fine.

Note, that this was very different than the original error, which was specifically indicating that the server terminated the response and returning the relevant status codes.